# How to append a special character in Oracle SQL when an exact match is found in the column

Tags: oracle

Table Details - Has 2 columns `ID` and `MSG_INFO`

```
ID - 1; MSG_INFO Party is carrying gold in a car which is made of gold

ID - 2; MSG_INFO Party is carrying whitegold in a car which made of gold
```

I want to write a query in which if I search for gold in the MSG_INFO column and if there is an exact match then I append ~ to gold and no action to be performed when there is no exact match.

Expected output

```
ID -1 ; MSG_INFO Party is carrying ~gold in a car which is made of ~gold
ID -2 ; MSG_INFO Party is carrying whitegold in a car which made of ~gold
```

Comment: You need to be more specific - what do you mean by "exact match"? Do you mean the letters **gold**, preceded by a non-letter (or at the beginning of the message) and followed by a non-letter(or at the end of the message)? If not, what else? Also - is Gold a match (capitalized)?

Comment: exact match is the word gold preceded by a non-letter and followed by a non-letter anywhere in the text. It can be capitalized as Gold or GOLD.If it matches then add ~ preceding the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle `REGEXP`, there is no `\b` pattern to match word boundaries. A commonly used solution looks something like this.

```
SELECT id,
       REGEXP_REPLACE (msg_info, '(^|\s|\W)(gold)($|\s|\W)', '\1~\2\3', 1,0,'i')
FROM   yourtable;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60576c/3)

This searches for the word gold at the start of the string, surrounded by a space on either side, end of string, or a non-word character (such as ? or -). `\1,\2,\3` represent the characters matched within the 1st,2nd and 3rd parentheses.

Comment: Can we reframe the query where to get the count to check how many times the exact match has occured and how many times we got a partial match.

Comment: @user3442679 : You could try `REGEXP_COUNT` for such purposes. You may post here on SO a question anytime, if you face difficulty in getting results.

Comment: Can you help me in the above query to find an match only when the word is separated by space, tab and comma only and nothing else.

Comment: @user3442679 : you could ask that as a separate question if you would like to have solution quickly b'coz it might take me some time to come back.

Comment: Need some tweaks on your answer, started a new question. Could you please help me here

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REPLACE function. Sample query below.

```
SELECT REPLACE('gold a gold a  agold  ggolg', ' gold ', '~gold')
  FROM dual;
```

In your case, the query could be,

```
SELECT id, REPLACE(msg_info, ' gold ', '~gold')
  FROM your_table;
```

Note: In the second argument, you can put spaces or not, it depends on you. Also, you can look for more details of the REPLACE function in the internet.