# Reg Exp - insert a special character (~) between the first and the third character and only when an exact match is present

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

My table has a column `MSG_INFO` with sample data:

```
Party is carrying gold in a car which is made of ,gold,
Party is carrying whitegold in a car which made of gold
```

I need a SQL expression that searches for `gold` and if there is an exact match then I append `~` after the first character of the exact match `gold` and no action to be performed when there is no exact match.

`gold` can only be surrounded by space or comma on either side.

Expected output:

```
Party is carrying g~old in a car which is made of ,g~old,
Party is carrying whitegold in a car which made of g~old
```

Note - After inserting `~` space before and after gold should still be preserved.

This is what I've started with:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (msg_info, '(^|\s|\W)(gold)($|\s|\W)', '\1~\2\3', 1,0,'i')
FROM   table;

Party is carrying ~gold in a car which is made of ,~gold,
Party is carrying whitegold in a car which made of ~gold
```

It correctly identifies the correct instances of `gold` but it puts the `~` before the word rather than after the first character.

Comment: Background question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973053/how-to-append-a-special-character-in-oracle-sql-when-an-exact-match-is-found-in

Answer (score 1):

Split `(gold)` into two patterns: `(g)(old)` in the search string, e.g.:

```
select regexp_replace('Party is carrying gold in a car which is made of ,gold,',
        '(^|\s|\W)(g)(old)($|\s|\W)', '\1\2~\3\4', 1,0,'i') from dual
union all
select regexp_replace('Party is carrying whitegold in a car which made of gold',
        '(^|\s|\W)(g)(old)($|\s|\W)', '\1\2~\3\4', 1,0,'i') from dual;


Party is carrying g~old in a car which is made of ,g~old,
Party is carrying whitegold in a car which made of g~old
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0160d/1 - Could you check the example , I tried modifying your query. It is not working as I expect. Is there something I am missing.

Comment: forget it , I know what the mistake is. The quotes was in the wrong place. Will confirm with another round of testing.

Comment: why are we introducing two patterns instead of one word to be searched, is it only for inserting the ~ we are splitting it up.

Comment: @user3442679 : If you don't need to match the case and simply want to replace `gold` with `g~old`, then splitting would not be required, we could simply use `'\1g~old\3'` as replacement pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it should work.

```
REGEX_REPLACE(msg_info,'([\s,](g)(o)(l)(d)[\s,])','\2
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex is a little different in that it uses nested groups.  Don't forget "Gold" at the start of the line.

```
SQL> with tbl(msg_info) as (
      select 'Party is carrying gold in a car which is made of ,gold,' from dual union all
      select 'Party is carrying whitegold in a car which made of gold' from dual union all
      select 'Gold Party gold is carrying whitegold gold goldstar gold' from dual
    )
    select regexp_replace(msg_info, '(( |,|^)g)(old( |,|$))', '\1~\3', 1, 0, 'i') after
    from tbl;

AFTER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Party is carrying g~old in a car which is made of ,g~old,
Party is carrying whitegold in a car which made of g~old
G~old Party g~old is carrying whitegold g~old goldstar g~old

SQL>
```